# Store UTF8 text to PHP variable and output it correctly

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

can you please provide some help, this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
    <?php
            $var = utf8_encode("nađžćča slovaćč");
            echo utf8_decode($var);
        ?>
    </div>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I did try several things: removing utf8_encode / decode, putting header () in php code, but none of this worked, so can you please tell me where am I doing it wrong, thx!

Comment: Have you tried to output "nađžćča slovaćč" as html, <html lang="en"> - this is what I am not sure of, you should leave it <html> only.

Comment: If your string _is_ utf8, which seems likely, just echo it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to encode/decode data. Simply, you may save file using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: yes, this helped. The fact is my editor didn't allow me to change the encoding (how strange is that?), so I opened the file in Notepad++, changed the encoding and woila, no encode/decode needed. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

You may get rid of this attribute lang="en". For me , I tried in different browsers and it works well

Answer (score 0):

No need to encode or decode data.